# Why application crashes when using express-rate-limit?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using express-rate-limit package version 6.0.1 to limit hits of request an I also had used express-rate-limit documentation found on https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit

However when I use this in my app, my application crashes.
I"m not understanding what is going on here. I have search allot for a conclusion but without any results.
Can someone give me an idea of what I'm doing wrong???

```
...

//Load env vars
dotenv.config({ path: "./config/config.env" });

//Connect to database
connectDB();

const app = express();

//Set Static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

// Body Parser
app.use(express.json());

// Cookie parser
app.use(cookieParser());

//Dev logging middleware
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  app.use(morgan("dev"));
}

// File uploading
app.use(fileUpload());

// Sanitize data
app.use(mongoSanitize());

// Set security headers
app.use(helmet());

// Prevent XSS attacks
app.use(xss());

//Rate limiting
const limiter = rateLimit({
  windowMs: 10 * 60 * 1000, // 10 mins
  max: 1,
});

app.use(limiter);

// Prevent http param pollution
app.use(hpp());

app.use(errorHandler);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const server = app.listen(
  PORT,
  console.log(
    `Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${PORT}`.yellow.bold
  )
);

//Handle unhandled promise rejections
process.on("unhandledRejection", (err, promise) => {
  console.log(`Error: ${err.message}`.red);
  // Close server & exit process
  server.close(() => process.exit(1));
});
```

[image: Screenshot of error message]

Merry Christmas gurus and keep on coding!!!

Comment: did you include the limiter module, as per docs: `const rateLimit = require('express-rate-limit')`

Comment: Hello @traynor, yes I have include the package in my project as you mentioned, yesterday I was thinking to downgrade the version and see if this can fix the problem!!

Comment: yeah, they moved to typescript.. I got it working with: `npm install express-rate-limit@5.5.1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add `.default` in `require`, like this `require('express-rate-limit').default`.

i found it on here https://github.com/nfriedly/express-rate-limit/issues/270

Comment: This had resolve the problem, thank you very much @husnaram